# Ordering SQL results by combined value of row in database

Tags: php, mysql

This is going to be a confusing one.. I'll try to explain it and provide as much information as possible. Basically, what I have is a website where people can upload the amount of kills they get in a game. What I'd like to do, is display people's combined, confirmed kills on a leaderboard.. This is proving harder than I expected (LOL).

Here's what my database looks like:

[image: Database Screenshot]

`submission` is the unique id of the entry.

`usergt` is the user's gamertag.

`image` is not important.

`userkilled` is the person they have killed.

`status` is the status of the confirmation of the kill.

`conftotal` is the total kills that we confirmed from the image (eg. entry 5 recorded 24 kills).

`submitted` is simply a unix timestamp of the submission date and time.

Here's my PHP on the page itself:

```
<?php
function getKills($gamertag) {
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "rpsanet_seals", "k_,2N2Xbu}mr", "rpsanet_seals");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);} 

    $sql = "SELECT conftotal FROM kills WHERE usergt='" . $gamertag . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $ctotalklls = 0;

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $ctotalklls = $ctotalklls + $row["conftotal"];
        }
    } else {
        $ctotalklls = 0;
    } 

    return $ctotalklls;

    $conn->close();
}
?>
            <div class="mykills_content">
                    <table class="mykills_table">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="mk_first">Avatar</th>
                            <th>Gamertag</th>
                            <th>Latest Victim</th>
                            <th class="mk_last">Total Kills</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php

                            $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "rpsanet_seals", "k_,2N2Xbu}mr", "rpsanet_seals");
                            if ($conn->connect_error) {die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);} 

                            $sql = "SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
                            FROM kills
                            WHERE status='confirmed'
                            GROUP BY usergt 
                            ORDER BY magnitude ASC 
                            LIMIT 5";
                            $result = $conn->query($sql);

                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                     echo '
                                     <tr>
                                         <td class="mykills_submission" data-submission="' . $row["submission"] . '">
                                             <div class="mykills_avatar">
                                                 <img src="https://avatar-ssl.xboxlive.com/avatar/' . $row["usergt"] . '/avatarpic-l.png" class="mykills_victim_avatar" draggable="false" />
                                             </div>
                                         </td>

                                         <td>
                                             ' . $row["usergt"] . '
                                         </td>

                                         <td>
                                             ' . $row["userkilled"] . '
                                         </td>

                                         <td>
                                             ' . getKills($row["usergt"]) . '
                                         </td>
                                     </tr>

                                     ';
                                 }
                                 echo '</table>'; 
                            } else {
                                 echo '</table><div class="fw-nokills">You have not submitted any kills yet.</div>';
                            }

                            $conn->close();
                        ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is what it looks like on the page:

[image: page sample]

I have no idea what I've done wrong or how to fix it. As you can see, the order is incorrect. It should go CheapApples12, then KILLER C00KIE X, then ancrobbo97.

If anything else is not clear, or any other info is needed, just comment and I'll get that to anyone as soon as I can..

I appreciate any help in advance :)

**IMPORTANT INFO:** The "Total Kills" that are being shown in the screenshot above are being generated from the getKills() function, not the database query result.

Comment: You can make things a lot easier for people to understand by deleting that image and adding a show create + a few lines of sample dat

Comment: don't need multiple query try this one SELECT *,sum(conftotal) as totalkills
                       FROM kills
                        WHERE status='confirmed'
                        GROUP BY usergt 
                        ORDER BY totalkills desc

Comment: It provides 0 results - https://i.gyazo.com/09b357f233a2145f02daf00c61ebe734.png

Comment: sorry there was some typo error now i updated my comment try it now

Comment: YES! IT WORKED!! Thankyou so much! I've been racking my brain for the last 2 hours!

Comment: can you try this query directly into your database and confirm that the query is working fine or not

Comment: i posted the comment as answer if it is useful mark it with green tick it useful for future user reference

Comment: Thankyou!! I'll do that right now :D

Comment: Glad to help you @BradleyHodges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple one liner use `sum(conftotal)` and use order by `sum(conftotal)`

```
SELECT *,sum(conftotal) as totalkills FROM kills WHERE status='confirmed' GROUP BY usergt ORDER BY totalkills desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.avatar, x.gamertag, x.magnitude AS magnitude FROM
( SELECT avatar,gamertag, COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
FROM kills
                            WHERE status='confirmed'
                            GROUP BY usergt 
                            LIMIT 5
) AS x
ORDER BY magnitude ASC
```

I can't test what I wrote, but I think you can get the logic out of it.
Using subqueries is slower, but they are quite powerfull.

Comment: Thankyou so much for responding, I don't see the point in people downvoting a question on a platform that is designed for mutual assistance.

Comment: I've just tried it, and it doesn't work for me.. It gives me 0 results

Comment: Update it with the right columns that you have in your db.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want a descending order to be displayed based on the TotalKills count, please try using the following query.

```
                       "SELECT *, COUNT(ref_column_name) AS magnitude 
                       FROM kills
                        WHERE status='confirmed'
                        GROUP BY usergt 
                        ORDER BY magnitude desc"
```

Comment: Hi, since you are using the getKills() functions to get the Total Kills, then doing this order by clause in query is not required, if you are using datatables.js to populate the data then you will have to put a sorting of the column "Total Kills" using javascript,  refer https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html